# Sailsjs database adapter for the microsoft access database

Tags: sails.js

I have reviewed all the npm packages and there doesnt seem to be a package available to access microsoft's access database through sailsjs?

Has another team created a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen adapter. But you can try [Node ODBC driver](https://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc)

To connect to .mdb file you need connection string. Here is list of list of connection strings for this driver: [Access connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).